# AS3 - Why is the class array not working properly?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, class, object

I have a class named tOne. The class code is below.

```
public class tOne extends MovieClip {
    private var _root:MovieClip;
    public var tPath:Array = new Array();

    public var index:int = 0;       

    public function tOne() {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
    }

    private function beginClass(e:Event):void {
        _root = MovieClip(root);            
        tPath = _root.tMovingPath; //Sets the tPath array to a bunch of coordinates
    }

    private function gameLoop(e:Event):void {
        if (tPath[index] != null) {             
            this.x = tPath[index].xCoord;
            this.y = tPath[index].yCoord;
            tPath.splice(index, 1); //Here is the problem

            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

I am create three instances of this class, so I have 3 tOne objects. Now my problem is, when I use the 'tPath.splice(index, 1)', it does not remove that index from one of the tOne objects, but from all three objects.

So if in the first object of tOne I have an array length of 3 and remove one of them, it removes one from the other two objects of tOne.

I don't understand why.

Can anyone explain to me what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your line

```
tPath = _root.tMovingPath;
```

you are setting tPath to reference an array. The references of all three objects will point to the same array.

What you need to do is make a [copy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee7.html) of that array. One way of doing it:

```
tPath = _root.tMovingPath.concat();
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I always thought that if you set an array equals to another array, the contents would get copied. I was wrong. Anyways, thank you.